# Do jobs in root's crontab still execute when logged in as another user?

Tags: linux, shell-script, cron, crontab

I have edited my root's crontab. Will root's cron jobs still run when I'm logged in as another user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cron daemon runs as a [*daemon*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29), and runs jobs irrespective of who, if anyone, is logged in.

(Remember that Unix used to run on big servers with hundreds of users, most of which would be be logged out at evening/night.)

Comment: Why, then, are there crontabs for different users as indicated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134906/how-do-i-list-all-cron-jobs-for-all-users

Comment: @Keyslinger The `crontab` is a file that lists what to do, while `cron` is the background process that actually *does* the things. It goes through all of crontabs for all of the users to find things to execute. Each user has their own crontab to allow each user to set their own cron jobs that other users can't mess with.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, root's cron jobs will still run even if you're logged in as another user.

Comment: Bad form circumventing the minimum character limit. Even if it *can* be answered in less, you should elaborate on your answer (like grawity did).